# WPF Popup Placement,How to configure it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

For instance, if I set the Placement="Bottom", but the parent is close to the bottom of the screen, then popup will show on top.

How to stop this behavior,Let it continue to show up below?

Comment: Do you mean below as in *partly out of screen* or below as in *slightly moved to the top*?

Comment: Yes,
I want it to always show at the bottom

Comment: Generally speaking, a question of the form *"Do you want `A` or `B`?"* should not be answered with *"Yes"*.

Comment: Always display at the bottom of the parent control